# NSFetchedResultsController -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I've done quite a bit of research on this issue, but found nothing that lead me to a solution. I am attempting to use `NSFetchedResultsController`, and getting this error when I run the app:

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil'
*** First throw call stack:

I have found that some people encountered this problem when using the `estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath` method, but I'm not using it.

Using an Exception Breakpoint revealed it's crashing at this line in the below block of code: `let frc = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: self.managedContext, sectionNameKeyPath: "date.theDate", cacheName: nil)`. It doesn't make it past here.

I have a print statement below it that never executes. The managedObjectContext does exist. `frc` is called for the first time in viewDidLoad (code below). I'll also include my AppDelegate code.

Thanks in advance!

Here's my relevant code:

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class TransactionsViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate {

    var containerDelegate: ContainerDelegate?

    var managedContext: NSManagedObjectContext!

    lazy var frc: NSFetchedResultsController = {
        // Initialize Fetch Request
        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "DailyTransactions")

        // Initialize Fetched Results Controller
        let frc = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: self.managedContext, sectionNameKeyPath: "date.theDate", cacheName: nil)

        print("Assigned frc complete.")

        // Configure Fetched Results Controller
        frc.delegate = self

        print("FRC finished")

        return frc
    }()
```

`frc` is first used in viewDidLoad by this:

```
    // Exectue Fetch Request
    do {
        try self.frc.performFetch()
    } catch {
        let fetchError = error as NSError
        print("\(fetchError), \(fetchError.userInfo)")
    }
```

**UPDATE:**

After using sort descriptions on the Fetch Request and changed the section key path the nil, I resolved this issue. I can even change section key path back to `date.theDate` and it will run fine.

Comment: Why is your sort descriptor key an empty string. I don't know what that would do, but it's not right.

Comment: That's just left over from when I was trying different things to ID/solve the problem. I've removed it from the post.

Comment: You are probably seeing a side-effect of another issue. Do you have an Exception Breakpoint in place? This will show exactly the line causing the problem. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13929518/nsarraym-insertobjectatindex-object-cannot-be-nil-how-determine-where-i

Comment: did you try without a section name key path ?

Comment: I have used an Exception Breakpoint and discovered it's crashing at this line: let frc = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: self.managedContext, sectionNameKeyPath: "date.theDate", cacheName: nil). I have also tried setting sectionNameKeyPath to nil with no luck.

Comment: Usually, FRC complains about absence of sort descriptors in fetch request. Try to set it to array of two sort descriptors – first on your section keypath, `date.theDate`, and second on some attribute of `DailyTransactions`.

Comment: Yes I discovered that it required the sort descriptor. Not sure what happened the first couple times through, but now with a sort descriptor and a different String in section keypath it works! And even now when I change section keypath back to "date.theDate" it works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After using sort descriptions on the Fetch Request and changing the section key path to nil, I resolved this issue. I can even change section key path back to date.theDate and it will run fine. My mistake was either somewhere else or somehow associated with Section key path.

Answer (score 0):

Your managed Context is zero. therefore you don't get anything. That is why it is not initialized, there should be a context , otherwise objects can't be propagated...

Comment: My managed context gets passed from a previous view controller.